# How can I install Texas Instrument's dvsdk?

Tags: software-installation

I'm running the latest Ubuntu. How can I install a file that doesn't even have a file extension? I followed the instructions, but I failed. Also apt doesn't do anything.

Here is a [link](http://software-dl.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/dvsdk/DVSDK_4_00/latest/index_FDS.html) to the file and the installation process.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you downloaded something like "dvsdk_dm368-evm_4_02_00_06_setuplinux" this is one of the annoying types of installer that is a shell script with the binaries embedded in it (in this case, almost 700M of binaries).

To install, you would do as it says in steps 5.2 and 5.3:

- chmod +x dvsdk_dm368-evm_4_02_00_06_setuplinux # and then
- ./dvsdk_dm368-evm_4_02_00_06_setuplinux # to execute the installer.

That is likely to work assuming you have the same environment that they expect with the same version of Ubuntu (which in this case is a 32bit version of Ubuntu 10.04, so the latest is likely too new).